# Iterated EMA formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on VBA macro, manipulating data on an excel sheet. I have closes of stocks and need to make a collection of *EMA* (exponential moving average) series. I need to iterate the same couple of formulas over 100 times, but respective to the cells. For example, the first iteration will be `=AVERAGE(D153:D164)` , then immediately beneath that will be `=(2/13)*D165+(11/13)*E164`, which will be format copied down (I'll do that). I need to perform these calculations every 70 rows, ending with `=AVERAGE(D8973:D8984)` & `(2/13)*D8985+(11/13)*E8984`. Can someone help me derive a functioning macro? Your help is sincerely appreciated.

EDIT: *To be more specific, I need to pass the row number as a variable to use in the formulas. If I see how to do so with one variable, I can use that as a foundation. The above 2 formulae are models, yet each instance of each formula will be unique.*
Again, thank You.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro when doing this for the first couple of times then setting up a loop? You will get an R1C1 set of formulas which then shoudln't need any parameters passing as they will work based on relative position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first formulas are the same, and you are always incrementing the same number of rows (70), this code should work. You can change some of my initial assumptions such as the starting cell, number of iterations, etc.

```
Sub EMAmakeAFunction()
'''''These can be changed as you need
Dim numberOrRowsToSkip As Integer: numberOFRowsToSkip = 70
Dim TrialsToExecute As Integer: TrialsToExecute = 1000
Dim firstFormula As Range: Set firstFormula = Range("D165")
Dim secondFormula As Range: Set secondFormula = Range("D166")
''''Rest of code should be pretty stable of above assumptions are correct.

Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To TrialsToExecute
    firstFormula.Offset(i * numberOFRowsToSkip).FormulaR1C1 = _
        firstFormula.FormulaR1C1
    secondFormula.Offset(i * numberOFRowsToSkip).FormulaR1C1 = _
        secondFormula.FormulaR1C1

Next i

End Sub
```